# How to post external references in playframework2.0

Tags: html, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a school project, for which I want to develop a web application similar (but simplified) to reddit. [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/) My problem is that I can't seem to be able to post references/hyperlinks that point outside of localhost:9000/ . All tags in the mold of the below example are changed, thus to point to localhost:9000/www.google.ro .

```
<!-- language: html -->
<a href="www.google.ro"> Go to google </a>
```

All hyperlinks are made relative. How can I go around this? Basically, block the interpreter from modifying my hyperlink?

Sorry for the poor formatting. It's my first post here :). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `<a href="http://www.google.ro">Go to google</a>`

Comment: I'll try as soon as I can (now I'm at work). Would be funny though, I swear I've tried out all kind of work arounds and every time, I'd end up with localhost:9000 being added to the beginning of the link.

Comment: BTW, that’s not the Play framework which prepends “localhost:9000” to your link but your browser. Unless you write the URL scheme, your browser will assume that your link points to your domain.

Comment: Will respond in about 6 hours when I get home. But yes, what you say makes a lot of sense, now that I've looked up URL formatting (talk about not knowing the basics). Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Thankssss. Yeah, it was exactly as you said, by specifying the URL scheme, now it's working fine.